# Wakanda connect 4D error session

Tags: wakanda, 4d-database

I launching a 4D method from Wakanda, I have this error :

```
{
"__ERROR": [
  {
"message": "The maximum number of sessions has been reached",
"componentSignature": "dbmg",
"errCode": 1823
}
],
}
```

I see 4D databases in Wakanda.

I use 4D rest and I have a method name `Test_WebService()` in 4D side. In Wakanda, I call the method by `ds.FA_UNITES.Test_WebService();` 
`FA_UNITES` is my table name

method `Test_WebService() 4D` side is `$0:="Hello"`

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: May you provide the error message in english language and with proper encoding. More details would also be helpful...

Comment: thanks, "message":The maximum number of sessions has been reached

Comment: I use 4D rest and I have a method name Test_WebService() in 4D side. In Wakanda, I call the method by ds.FA_UNITES.Test_WebService(); FA_UNITES is my table name

Comment: method Test_WebService() 4D side is $0:="Hello"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "The maximum number of sessions has been reached" error indicates you do not have the appropriate licenses to use 4D Mobile.

I believe [4D Mobile Expansion](http://www.4d.com/products/4dv14/4dmobile.html) is required to develop 4D Mobile applications. It grants you two 4D Mobile Client sessions. If you do have 4D Mobile Expansion, please check if it is activated properly.